# iPad DatePicker Phonegap Plugin not working

Tags: jquery, iphone, ipad, html, cordova

iPad DatePicker Phonegap Plugin not working on ipad, instead it is working on iphone.

Any suggestion ?

```
plugins.datePicker.show({ date: new Date(), mode: 'mode', allowOldDates: false }, CallBackDate);
```

Comment: When i click on my "datepicker show()" button, i have nothing... just
a little black line on the middle of my screen.

Comment: My suggestion is 'add your code so we can help'.

Comment: plugins.datePicker.show({
       date: new Date(),
       mode: 'mode', 
     allowOldDates: false
   }, CallBackDate);

This code is using date picker plugin and works fine for iPhone but show black line in iPad.

Answer (score 0):

What version iOS are you testing on? If it's prior to 5, input type="date" won't render a spinner.
Instead of that, you can use mobiscroll with the iOS skin.

Check out http://mobiscroll.com

Comment: Did anybody manage to resolve this issue? I'm experiencing the same bug using Cordova/PhoneGap 3.0.0 and the datepicker plugin found here... https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/iOS/DatePicker